# Nextjs dynamic routes - how to pass props from parent to dynamic route child

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Using next@latest, and their dynamic routing features. I have

`/pages/index.tsx` and `/pages/department/[slug]/index.tsx`. The first index.tsx is using `getStaticProps` to pull in a bit of data. During dev this data is an auto-generated array of objects. I am then rendering these objects via props.departments in the index component.

I am showing a list of departments, and want to link an item to a single page:

```
{departments.map(dept => (
  <Link
    as={`/department/${dept.slug}`}
    href="/department/[slug]"
  >
    ...
  </Link>
)}
```

There seems to be no way to pass down props since there is no obvious parent/child connection.

Do I have to query a single department in the [slug]/index.tsx, should I use react useContext, or is there a better design approach which would take care of the issue?

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose to use context API to share state between the two routes `/pages/index.tsx` and `/pages/department/[slug]/index.tsx` you have to wrap your `App` component with the context provider in `_app.tsx`. Which will lead to another problem, if you have three more routes which don't need the data they will also be children to the context provider without using the values from the context.

I suggest querying the data in data fetching methods i.e. `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` if using static generation and `getServerSideProps` is using server-side rendering for a single department.

Here is what some pseudo-code might look like for `/pages/department[slug]/index.tsx`

#### if using static generation

```js
export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  let paths: {params: { slug: string;}}[] = [];

  // generate the paths for the pages you want to render
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false // false if you know all the slugs that you want to generate ahead of time  
  }

}

interface IProps {
  // props for your page
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<IProps> = async (context) => {
   // get the slug
   const slug = context.params?.slug;

   // query the data based on slug

   return {
     props: {
       // return the queried data as props
     }
   }
}
```

#### If using server-side-rendering

```js
interface IProps {
  // data you need as props
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<IProps> = async (context) => {
  // get the slug
  const slug = context.params.slug

  // query the data

  return {
    props: {
       // return the queried data
    } 

  }

}
```

P.S- `getStaticProps` will be called once for each path returned from `getStaticPaths` at build time. `getServerSideProps` will be called as per request basis, so choose how do you want to fetch the data based on your need.